# Rails not redirecting on PUT request, sending 406 back instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, fetch

I'm working on a bell schedule creator for a school project I'm working on. The bell schedule creation on the client is handled with a React component, and when it comes time to update, the component calls this fetch request:

```
fetch(`/bell-schedules/${this.state.updatingId}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'text/html',
                },
                redirect: "follow",
                referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
                body: JSON.stringify({ name: this.state.name, schedule: json})})
```

On the server, these requests are handled by the BellSchedulesController, and the method for handling this type of route is coded as so:

```
# PUT /bell-schedules/:id
  def update
    set_bell_schedule
    respond_to do |format|
      if @schedule.update(name: params[:name], schedule: params[:schedule])
        redirect_to action: 'index'
      else
        head 400
      end
    end
  end
```

Index is a simple method that gets all the bell schedules and renders them in a table; that method works fine, other routes point to it and it renders normally. Unfortunately, when I send this PUT request, rather than getting a redirect to that page showing the table of bell schedules, I instead get back a **406 Not Acceptable**. I also know that the bell schedule is actually updating, I've inspected the entry in the rails console.

How do I handle redirects in PUT requests? I'm also having an issue similar to this in a POST request, but I've found a hack around it there; that hack won't work in this one.

Comment: The reason you could be getting a 406 is that you're using `Accept: 'text/html'`. Unless I'm missing some sort of react magic redirects when doing XHR requests do work like in classic server side apps - your server just sends back a location header and possibly some JSON and its up to you to actually reload the window or do something else with the results.

Comment: This is also very uniomatic in terms of building a REST API. When you update a resource your server should not really care about redirecting anywhere. It just returns the appropriate headers such as `200 - OK`. I guess you could return 3XX and a location header if updating the resource changes its location but doesn't seem to be the case here. Maybe you're just approaching the problem with a classical web app mindset and you should actually be handling "redirecting" (refreshing the view) on the client side.

Comment: To explain that point in other terms. `redirect_to action: 'index'` makes sense when you have a classical app rendering HTML. But to a client sending ajax requests its a bit daft. Its  like the client saying "PLS Update this" adnd the server responding "HERE IS ALL THE THINGS, HAVE FUN WIITH THEM!" when the client really just wants to know if updating the thing worked or not.

Comment: @max interesting. But you could say it's problematic to redirect POST/PUT even on classical HTML rendering apps - from tonyarra's answer I see that people misuse HTTP when they redirect to index/show after a POST/PUT, that's not what the headers were originally designed to do.

Comment: @JoelBlum yes. Its kind of a dirty pragmatic workaround. Creating a resource should really just result in rendering a view and it as a response, but that means that you would have to setup the ivars and  to display that view and redirecting also solves the browser history issue.

Comment: @tech0tron I updated my answer after testing it out locally.

Comment: @JoelBlum I'm not sure how it's improper. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303), this is the expected usage when a PUT/POST request updates a resource, and the response is a redirect to an information page, like a confirmation, rather than a representation of the updated resource. In this case, `index` is acting as the confirmation or informational redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the issue appears to be two-fold - the use of `respond_to` and the redirect status. Updating my answer as follows:

1. Wrap `redirect_to` in `format.html`. As @joel-blum suggested, removing the `respond_to` block entirely also solves this issue; however, I still required the 303 status for this to work locally
2. Use a [303](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) (`:see_other`) status code for the redirect

```
def update
  set_bell_schedule
  respond_to do |format|
    if @schedule.update(name: params[:name], schedule: params[:schedule])
      format.html { redirect_to action: 'index', status: :see_other }
    else
      head 400
    end
  end
end
```

### Explanation

#### respond_to

When using [respond_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html) in your controller actions, you need to specify what format(s) your responses are targeted for. In this case, your request is `Accept: text/html`, so you need to specify that as the target format. `format.all` or removing `respond_to` entirely would also work here, unless you need to return different responses based on the `Accept` header.

#### 303 Redirect

Standard 301/302 redirects for dangerous HTTP methods (anything other than GET) generally won't be honored by the browser.

The browser will attempt to redirect to `index` using the same HTTP method that the request was initially made in: `PUT`. This will result in a 404. Setting the redirect status to 303 ensures that the browser performs the `index` redirect with a GET request.

A typical redirect response to a GET request indicates that the requested resource has moved (temporarily or permanently).

For PATCH/PUT/POST/DELETE, The browser has to assume that the resource was found at the expected location, but its data has changed since the initial request was made. The server is just informing the client that the response for this action exists at another location.

For the sanctity of the HTTP contract, a different status code is needed to indicate this situation. 303 informs the client of the location of this response location and suggests that it can be accessed with a GET request.

Comment: Unless I'm missing some React magic here an fetch request won't cause the browser to automatically change `window.location` or do anything at all really no matter what response code is sent. The `redirect` option for the Fetch API will just cause the XHR request to follow the redirect - its still up to the programmer to actually do anything with the results.

Comment: @max actually, it looks to be a combination of the `respond_to` issue and the `see_other`. I was able to recreate the problem locally with the same `fetch` call and an API controller with `update` and `index` routes. Without setting status to `see_other`, the response object in the `then` callback has a status of 404. With `see_other`, the response object had a status of 200.

Fixing the 406 specifically required wrapping the redirect in `format.html { ... }`

Comment: @max the 404 that occurs on the `update` request without the 303 status code is due to the fact that Rails attempts to redirect to the `index` action using the same method that it received the request. There is no PUT action for the `index` route, so this results in a 404. Setting the redirect status to 303 ensures that Rails redirects to the `index` route using a GET request.

Comment: @max correction: Rails is not the one attempting to do the redirect to `index` using `PUT`. This is happening as part of the `fetch` request. It receives the redirect response from Rails and then performs a second request in the browser based on it. This is where it uses the 303 to determine that it needs to make the request to `index` as a GET. This has nothing to do with React. It's purely the javascript fetch API

Answer (score 0):

Googling your problem it seems to come from the `respond_to ... |format|` block, try getting rid of it and see if it helps. You don't seem to be using it correctly, you are not doing anything with the format and maybe that's why it's blowing up.